# MDX datetime comparison

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I have a MDX calculated measure for rolling 30-day totals, and I want to mask the calculation for future members. I'm trying to use a CASE statement and the comparison does not work correctly. If the key of the Fiscal Month member is a datetime, shouldn't this work?

```
CASE  
WHEN [Time].[Fiscal Month].CurrentMember < NOW()  
THEN 1  
ELSE 0  
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative, and sometimes better performing approach could be to add an attribute to your date dimension along the lines of "IsFuture".

Depending on your data load/processing schedule you could have a field in your datawarehouse or a calculated column in your dsv precalculating if the date is in the future or not.

Instead of performing an on the fly calculation with an `IIF` in your MDX you could then create a calculated measure using [`SCOPE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/mdx-scripting-scope) like this (untested, from memory)

```
Scope   
 (   
    [Date].[IsFuture].&[0]
 ) ;     

   This = 1;  
end scope;
```

Just an idea I'm offering, your question doesn't provide a lot of detail to create a working piece of sample code but this could be an alternative approach.
This would return empty if the date is in the future instead of 0 but depending on your requirements that could provide better results if your client is only returning `NONEMPTY`/`NONEMPTYCROSSJOIN` results.

Comment: The approach that seems to work best is having a PeriodOrdinal attribute in my time dimension where the current period is '0' and other periods are positive or negative integers. I have an existing business process to shift the period at closing, so the time dimension gets re-processed then anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The Function `NOW()` returns a DateTime, you cannot compare that to a Member. Dependending on the definition of the Time dimension you can convert the result of `NOW()` to a member using MDX-Function `StrToMember`, but there is no lower than on Members.

I use keys of the format "yyyyMMdd" for my time dimension. So that key is comparable like this:

`WHEN [Time].[Time].CurrentMember.Properties("Key") < Format(Now(),"yyyyMMdd") THEN 1`